# Ajax call doesn't work without an alert call

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on the flag 'isConformpage' we are adding some log in the database.

The log code is triggered via an AJAX call.

The flag condition is not being passed even though the value is 'true'.

It works if I add an `alert()` before the `if` condition.

PS: `WriteLog1` method return in VB.net. Mentioning here although it doesn't have any impact on the question.

```
try {
  setTimeout(function () {
    //your code to be executed after 5 second
    if (isconformpage) {

      var split = document.getElementById("hdnconfirmpage").value.split("#");
      transaction = split[0];
      transaction = jQuery.parseJSON(transaction);
      user = jQuery.parseJSON(split[1]);
      component = jQuery.parseJSON(split[2]);

      //Tagging log start
      var pathurl = "/" + loc[1] + "/thankyou.aspx/WriteLog1";
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: pathurl,
        data: '{Message: "' + "-" + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        // success: OnSuccess1,
        failure: function (response) {}
      });
      // Tagging log end
    }
  }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: In what way is this related to VB.NET??

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: What do you check with alert?

Comment: What's the value of `isconformpage` when it's ran ?

Comment: @Visual Vincent, the back end log method written in VB.Net

Comment: @VisualVincent I think he's just saying (for the sake of completeness) his ajax call is to a VB.NET backend endpoint, but you're right that it's not relevant

Comment: Where does `isconformpage` come from? At what point is it set?

Comment: Visual Vincent, the back end log method written in VB.Net
Chris, It is not creating any log in DB. Actually the condition been skipped though it meets the condition

Fefux ,it was just and random debug trail and error method I used to...in fact it works if I use it.But I can''t deliver with an alert.

Jeff Noel, It is always true. Getting skipped with a false is understandable.

Comment: Based on the code working when an `alert()` is in place (giving time for the ajax call to complete before the program completes the most likely suspect is a concurrency issue. Remember ajax is asynchronous (it's in the name). Spend some time looking into how to use callbacks with ajax calls to deal with async issues. It's a common issue with a range of common answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are "Missing *`catch`* or *`finally`* after `try`"

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch